# Scanning from Book - Gradient Removal

Tags: image-processing

This sample image:

[image: img]

is warped on the left side.

I don't want to dewarp, but just to remove shadow gradient (caused by book's spine). I guess gradient can be calculated from upper part of the image and that information can be used for reconstruction.

First I thought to apply some layer transformation in Photoshop. I took upper part with clear gradient and scaled it vertically to cover whole image in new layer. Then I did layer difference:

[image: img]

but while upper part is acceptably reconstructed, colored part is not.

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this in Photoshop, or Python/SciPy/OpenCV, or Matlab?

Comment: try applying a saturation filter with same mask in photoshop

Comment: Hi geometrikal ;) Can you post it as answer and paste result screenshot? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to divide the gradient rather than subtract it. Here's what the result looks like:

[image: Gradient Removal]

Comment: This is really cool! How did you extract the gradient?

Comment: Oh, same way as the OP did (I think). Took the top section and scaled it vertically.

Comment: Cool, I suspected so. = )

Comment: Thanks, it works great. From the layer operation blend naming, I assume you use Gimp ;)

Comment: I actually used PS (CS6), but was thinking more about math than blend modes :)